# LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks onLoadFinished not called

Tags: android

I'm having issue with `onLoadFinished` of `LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks` not being called after `CursorLoader` query data from the `ContentProvider`.

This issue happened after updating from appcompat 20 to appcompat 23.The app have the implementation of `SyncAdapter`.

Below is the flow of data syncing:

- users swipe to refresh --> ContentResolver.requestSync --> SyncAdapter.onPerformSync --> get data from API --> ContentResolver apply batch --> ContentResolver.notifyChange(URI, null, false)

After `ContentResolver` notify the changes, within the corresponding fragment, I have a `ContentObserver` that observe the particular URI and it did get the notification regards the changes in database. In the `onChange` method, it will `restartLoader` which will ask the `CursorLoader` to query and then pass the cursor to `LoaderManager` to update UI. The problem is that after querying, `onLoadFinished` in `LoaderManager` is not called and the UI is not updated.

Any help will be appreciated.